# Parse an XML and giving the value of a child node to a String

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-xml

I want to give the value of a child node in XML which is a URL and then put this value in a String. I used HashMap after parsing the XML to put the map in a list (songList). thumb_url in xml contains the value of the URL and I want to put that value in a String called "link".

```
    // XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
```

And:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));



        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);

    }
```

I actually want to give the "link" to "new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(link);" to be downloaded after pressing the row of the songList.
Best regards everybody.

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The trick is that I should pass the link form adapter. I add a tag to the view into `getView()` of adapter. `view.setTag(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_LINK));`. Then get this value in main activity by `String Link = view.getTag().toString();`

I hope this can help someone :)